# Compute average of two double?

Tags: java

I am trying compute average of two double value, but it dose not work truly. I think it is "rounding error" am I right? and how can I fix it?

```
point.get(0)=1

point.get(1)=4

double Average = (double)(point.get(0) + point.get(1) / 2);
```

**Output:**

> Average: 3.0

Why?

Comment: This code would not compile? Please provide a larger code listing.

Comment: I would also suggest using `0.5 * (point(.get(0) + point.get(1))` instead of dividing by 2 every time.  Multiplication is a faster operation than division.

Comment: @Jared Division by a simple constant is highly likely to be transformed into a multiplication somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 7):

```
double Average = (double)(point.get(0) + point.get(1) / 2);
```

is executed as

```
Average = (double)(1 + 4/2)  = (double) (1+2) = 3.0
```

**Problem**

Divison(/) has higher precedence than addition(+)

**Fix**

You need to add brackets for proper calculation:

```
double Average = (double)((point.get(0) + point.get(1)) / 2);
```

should execute as:

```
Average = (double)((1 + 4)/2)  = (double) (5/2) = 2.5
```

Comment: Good explanation, I think all answers should explain problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
double Average = (double)(point.get(0) + point.get(1) / 2)
```

Operator precedence trouble. Try this:

```
double Average = (point.get(0) + point.get(1)) / 2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the order of operators - the `/` has a higher precedence than `+`, so you are actually getting 1 + (4/2) which does equal 3.

Try this instead:

```
 double Average = (double)((point.get(0) + point.get(1)) / 2);
```

The extra brackets will correct your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Division takes precedence over addition. Hence,

```
Average = (double)(1 + 4/2)  = (double) (1+2) = 3.0
```

You should probably make it more like

```
Average = (double)((1+4)/2)
```